# php ¿Cómo eliminar un objeto de un arreglo en PHP para evitar ser reutilizado?

Tags: php, array, object, offset

Tengo el siguiente caso Hipotético: Dispongo de un conjunto de "Gift Cards" (10 por ejemplo) éstas tienen distintos montos (3$, 2$ y 1$) y **necesito asignar solo algunas** de estas Gift Cards, digamos que solo asignaré 3 en este caso (1x 2$) para "Juan" otra (1x 2$) para "Victor" y (1x 2$) para "Diana", **el caso es que a nivel de código solo cuento con el Monto para hacer la asignación** pese a que **cada Gift Card posee su propio ID** osea, **"no puedo reasignarla"**

Un ejemplo muy básico ideado solo para hacer pruebas seria el siguiente:

```
<?php
class GiftCard{
    public $id;
    public $amount;
    public $name;

    function __construct($id) {
         $this->id = $id;
         $this->amount = rand(1,3);
    }

    public function setAttributes($attr){
         foreach(get_class_vars(self::class) as $field => $val){
             if(array_key_exists($field, $attr)){
                 $this->$field = $attr[$field];
             }

         }
     }
 }
```

Intanciaré mis Gift Cards con montos al hazar e identificadores consecutivos:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
     $voidModels[] = new GiftCard($i);
 }
```

Creo el arreglo con los datos de los ganadores:

```
$data = [
         ['amount' => 2, 'name' => "Juan"],
         ['amount' => 1, 'name' => 'Diana'],
         ['amount' => 2, 'name' => "Victor"],
    ];
```

Acá la implementación que estoy intentando hacer:

```
$loadedModels = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $pos = array_search($row['amount'], array_column((array) $voidModels, 'amount'));
    if (is_numeric($pos)) {
        $model = $voidModels[$pos];
        $model->setAttributes($row);
        array_push($loadedModels, $model);
    }
    unset($voidModels[$pos]);//<--- con esto intento evitar reutilizar el objeto

}
```

El problema está en que obtengo el siguiente error:

```
**NOTICE** Undefined offset: 0
```

Cabe destacar que el error no siempre aparece :S

- ¿Por que sucede esto?
- ¿Que puedo hacer en dicha situación?

Comment: Acabo de encontrar una solución tentativa, pero no responde la pregunta, la solución fué hacer un segundo arreglo con las posiciones de los montos a modo de un indice y destruir la referencia a la posicion este, en lugar de hacerlo al arreglo de objetos :

Answer (score 0):

Quizá sea por que el índice `$pos` no exista como tal. Deberías saber preguntar también si el índice existe y no está vacio.

```
$loadedModels = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $pos = array_search($row['amount'], array_column((array) $voidModels, 'amount'));
    if (is_numeric($pos) && isset($pos) && !empty($pos)) {
        $model = $voidModels[$pos];
        $model->setAttributes($row);
        array_push($loadedModels, $model);
    }
    unset($voidModels[$pos]);//<--- con esto intento evitar reutilizar el objeto

}
```

Con eso ya tendrías blindado que no ocurra el error.